# Open a actvity when a if statement comes true

Tags: android

Hi I want to open a activity when a if statement comes true. like "if gameStatus are equal to 12, then open scoreActivity". The Code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Game6x4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int numberOfElements;
    private int[] buttonGraphicLocations;
    private MemoryButton selectedButton1;
    private MemoryButton selectedButton2;
    private boolean isBusy = false;
    public int gameStatus;
    public int gameScore;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_mode);

        gameScore = 0;
        gameStatus = 0;

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_6x4);

        int numColumns = gridLayout.getColumnCount();
        int numRow = gridLayout.getRowCount();

        numberOfElements = numColumns * numRow;

        MemoryButton[] buttons = new MemoryButton[numberOfElements];

        int[] buttonGraphics = new int[numberOfElements / 2];

        buttonGraphics[0] = R.drawable.card1;
        buttonGraphics[1] = R.drawable.card2;
        buttonGraphics[2] = R.drawable.card3;
        buttonGraphics[3] = R.drawable.card4;
        buttonGraphics[4] = R.drawable.card5;
        buttonGraphics[5] = R.drawable.card6;
        buttonGraphics[6] = R.drawable.card7;
        buttonGraphics[7] = R.drawable.card8;
        buttonGraphics[8] = R.drawable.card9;
        buttonGraphics[9] = R.drawable.card10;
        buttonGraphics[10] = R.drawable.card11;
        buttonGraphics[11] = R.drawable.card12;

        buttonGraphicLocations = new int[numberOfElements];

        shuffleButtonGraphics();

        for(int r=0; r < numRow; r++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c <numColumns; c++)
            {
                MemoryButton tempButton = new MemoryButton(this, r, c, buttonGraphics[buttonGraphicLocations[r * numColumns + c]]);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    tempButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
                }
                tempButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                buttons[r * numColumns + c] = tempButton;
                gridLayout.addView(tempButton);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void shuffleButtonGraphics(){
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            buttonGraphicLocations[i] = i % (numberOfElements / 2);
        }
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            int temp = buttonGraphicLocations[i];

            int swapIndex = rand.nextInt(16);

            buttonGraphicLocations[i] = buttonGraphicLocations[swapIndex];

            buttonGraphicLocations[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

    private int buttonGraphicLocations(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(isBusy) {
            return;
        }

        MemoryButton button = (MemoryButton) view;

        if(button.isMatched) {
            return;
        }

        if(selectedButton1 == null)
        {
            selectedButton1 = button;
            selectedButton1.flip();
            return;
        }

        if(selectedButton1.getId()== button.getId())
        {
            return;
        }


        if (selectedButton1.getFrontDrawableId()== button.getFrontDrawableId())
        {
            button.flip();

            button.setMatched(true);

            if (selectedButton1 != null) {
                selectedButton1.setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("not null");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("null");
            }
            if (selectedButton2 != null) {
                selectedButton2.setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("not null");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("null");
            }

            gameStatus = gameStatus + 1;
            gameScore = gameScore + 10;

            if (gameStatus == 12){
                Intent it = new Intent(Game6x4Activity.this, ActivityScore.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }

            selectedButton1 = null;

            return;
        }
        else
       {
            selectedButton2 = button;
            selectedButton2.flip();
            isBusy = true;

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    selectedButton2.flip();
                    selectedButton1.flip();
                    selectedButton1 = null;
                    selectedButton2 = null;
                    isBusy = false;
                }
            },500);
            return;
       }
    }
}
```

The activity that i want to open will show to the player his score. the activity is equal to all game modes, there will be some test to the app understant what path should go on. test like this one:
"

```
if (gameStatus == 12) {
            gameScore = gameScore*55;
            TextView scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            scoreText.setText(gameScore);
        }
        else if (gameStatus == 15){
```

"
There are 4 game modes: This is the 6x4 game, where we can find 24 cards (12 images).

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (gameStatus == 15){
 Intent intent = new Intent(Game6x4Activity.this, NextActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

I think, you are asking for this. You can pass value to another activity with

```
intent.putExtra("key",desired value);
```

Comment: when 
if (gameStatus == 12){
                Intent it = new Intent(Game6x4Activity.this, ActivityScore.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
there's what i have to pass to another activity

Comment: The game is working fine till gameStatus get to 12, when it happen, the game goes back to the main title...